# error: cannot find symbol BitmapTransformation/BitmapPool

Tags: java, android, androidx

I got the following error:

cannot find symbol BitmapTransformation/BitmapPool

I found this code online and wonder if there is any way to edit it to fit in androidx?

Code: https://gist.github.com/David-Hackro/839ba14f220bb513b4a2735c29a4eb0e

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the imports, those classes are from some `com.bumptech.glide` package, which looks like [this one](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

So add that as a dependency in your app ([follow their instructions)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#download) and you should be good to go

Comment: Yes that's what I did but it says can't resolve bumptech..

Comment: You added these in your app module's build.gradle file and let it sync? ``repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}`` if it still doesn't work do a ``Clean`` from the ``Build`` menu, and if that doesn't work do ``Invalidate Caches / Restart`` from the ``File`` menu, see if that gets it working