# Glide error .bitmapTransform on 4.12.0 version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

I am using glide having gradel version 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
for this the bitmap Transform works properly but when i update the gradel version to  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'.There showing error in .bitmapTransform.
I used to put MainActivity.this or this: but no use

```
  Glide.with(mContext).load(userDetailPojo.getProfileImage())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_user)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .bitmapTransform(new GlideCircleTransformation(getApplicationContext()))
                            .into(profilePic);
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @tomerpacific- cannot find symbol.bitmapTransform(new GlideCircleTransformation(mContext.getApplicationContext()))
                        ^
  symbol:   method bitmapTransform(GlideCircleTransformation)
  location: class RequestBuilder<Drawable>

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541697/error-cannot-find-symbol-bitmaptransformation-bitmappool).

Comment: @tomerpacific-I try the above method by adding annotation processor &  by cleaning and Invalid caches & restart but same error is showing